# Memory usage with and without initialization to null

Tags: java, memory, initialization

Does not initialising an instance variable save any memory?

For example, comparing the following two classes:

```
public class Class1 {
    private String s;
    // getter/setter for s
}

public class Class2 {
    private String s = "";
    // getter/setter for s
}
```

Assuming there's already a String constant of `""` elsewhere, does `new Class1()` consume less memory than `new Class2()`?

Comment: It's implicitly initialized with `null` anyways.

Answer (score 2):

No, by default the not initialized variables are set to null. Some other default initialization rules for the primitive types are:

- `boolean` - is always set to false.
- `int`,`float` and `double`  - are set to zero.

Answer (score 1):

Potentially depending on the JVM implementation. The main difference between the two is the code generated. `Class2` will have explicitly set the value of `s` to something is all cases. Whereas `Class1` could potentially have never set `s` to something specific leading to unexpected behavior.

Comment: "whereas Class1 could potentially have never set s to something specific leading to unexpected behaviour" As far as I know s will always be initialized to default value null according to specification. Do you have any link supporting your statement?

Comment: looked at the byte code. setting to null will load constant value 0 into the reference. not setting does nothing at the byte code level, I would expect the JVM initlise it properly being that it is a common practice, hence unexpected behaviour if the JVM does not.

Answer (score 0):

there is no difference if you initialize it to null (default value) or not as it will be anyway initialized so I dont think there'll be any memory usage difference.

But generally for better understanding (no need to remember default values for all code readers) it seems good to have them initialized explicitly.